# How to make sure that both x and y axes of plot are of equal sizes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make `x` and `y` axes be of equal lengths (*i.e* **the plot minus the legend should be square** ). I wish to plot the legend outside (I have already been able to put legend outside the box). The span of `x axis` in the data (`x_max - x_min`) is not the same as the span of `y axis` in the data (`y_max - y_min`).

This is the relevant part of the code that I have at the moment:

```
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=15 )
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
```

The following link is an example of an output plot that I am getting : [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To219.png)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would `plt.axis('scaled')` be what you're after? That would produce a square plot, if the data limits are of equal difference.

If they are not, you could get a square plot by setting the aspect of the axes to the ratio of xlimits and ylimits.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.plot([-2.5, 2.5], [-4,13], "s-")
ax1.axis("scaled")

ax2.plot([-2.5, 2.5], [-4,13], "s-")
ax2.set_aspect(np.diff(ax2.get_xlim())/np.diff(ax2.get_ylim()))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will it matter if the legend is outside of the plot? I will like to have the part of the plot which is without the legend be a square (I will like to have the legend besides this square plot).  In my case, the data limits are not of equal difference.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if there is another subplot, or a legend next to the plot for this to work. I'd say try it out and see if you're happy with the result, else come back and explain any further problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it. It works, but there is this one issue - the sides of the plot get cut (this is with me using `plt.tight_layout()`. Here is the plot that I am getting after using the above suggestions. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn6zj.png ) How can I not have the sides of the figure cut?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Did you call tight_layout before setting the aspect?

Comment: I called tight_layout after setting the aspect. I don't have subplots, so I tried this method which is based on your suggestion. This is what I am doing in the relevant section of the code: **1st line:**  `axes = plt.gca()` , **2nd line:** `axes.set_aspect( np.diff(axes.get_xlim())/np.diff(axes.get_ylim()) )` , **3rd line :**  `plt.tight_layout()` , **4th line:** `plt.savefig('filename.png')`

Comment: I think I would need a verifiable example ([mcve]) to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have to is manually set the limits, assuming that you know the size of your dataset.

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
```

A better option would be to iterate through your data to find the maximum x- and y-coordinates, take the greater of those two numbers, add a little bit more to that value to act as a buffer, and set `xmax` and `ymax` to that new value. You can use a similar method to set `xmin` and `ymin`: instead of finding the maximums, find the minimums.

To put the legend outside of the plot, I would look at this question: [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Comment: I have already been able to put legend outside the box (The figure shows as much). The span of `x axis` in the data (`x_max - `x_min) is not the same as the span of `y axis` in the data (`y_max - `y_min). The only thing I want is to make x and y axes be of equal lengths (i.e the plot minus the legend should be square ).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think you should be able to do what I described above. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Nicholas: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I tried your suggestion. This is what I tried:   plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=15 )
  axes = plt.gca()

  xmin = np.min( XX[ : , 0 ] )
  xmax = np.max( XX[ : , 0 ] )
  ymin = np.min( XX[ : , 1 ] )
  ymax = np.max( XX[ : , 1 ] )

  axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
  axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])