# Same length of ticks in multiplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

How to set to have the same scale/length of ticks in all subplots? I would like to set length of all xticks according to the forth subplot. I mean that all axis named y will have the same space between ticks 0 and 2, all axis named x will have the same space between -1 and 0. Maybe it would be sufficient to set plot as squares. How please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

# Plot figure with size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))

# Subplots
fig1 = plt.subplot(231)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig1.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)
fig1.set_ylim(-1.15e-14,0.01e-14)

fig2=plt.subplot(232)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig2.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)
fig2.set_ylim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)

fig3=plt.subplot(233)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig3.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)
fig3.set_xlim(0e-13,2e-13)

# Subplots with arrows
fig4=plt.subplot(234)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig4.set_xlim(-1.15e-14,0.01e-14)
fig4.set_ylim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)

fig5=plt.subplot(235)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig5.set_xlim(-7.3e-15,7.3e-15)
fig5.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)

fig6=plt.subplot(236)
plt.plot(x, y**2)
fig6.set_xlim(-1.5e-14,0e-14)
fig6.set_ylim(0e-13,1.2e-13)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is outlined best by [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082325/10659910) by [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest). Basically you manually calculate the scaling to adhere to the ratio between the `y` and `x` limits of each existing axis by something like

```py
fig1.set_aspect(np.diff(fig1.get_xlim())/np.diff(fig1.get_ylim()))
```

But please note that this must be done after any calls to `set_ylim()` and `set_xlim()` as it must use the *final* limits in order to correctly calculate the requisite ratio. `set_xticks()` and `set_yticks()` can safely be called before or after with the same effect.

Applying this to each of the six `axes` will produce

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile To be quite honest I wasn't confident I knew what was being asked due to the wording of the question and title, therefore I'm not confident comparing it to the linked question at the level of certainty to raise a flag - particularly considering there are 6k waiting in the close vote queue.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Was at 8k a few days ago, and you need 3k rep to review those flags. 33's not bad compared to my 12...

Comment: @WilliamMiller Wait, how do you get only 12? This site is just depressing, man...

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I've raised a whopping total of 17 flags haha, maybe because I spend on here most of my time answering

Comment: @WilliamMiller Ah right, you get more flags based on the number of net helpful flags, not just reputation. Well you better start working on that close vote queue, I’m working overtime ;)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile At the rate you're going you might hit 3k rep before me, then it'll be your problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203840/discussion-between-william-miller-and-alexander-cecile).